# How to continue an INSERT after a SaveChanges () error in Entity Framework (in VB Net)

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, insert, access-violation

How to continue an INSERT after a SaveChanges () error in Entity Framework (in VB Net)...After Violation PK.
- the program stops on db.SaveChange()(Even in a try catch...Catch no working)
- I would like to ignore this error and continue.
- the constraint PK is a date

```
                    For Each cpt As dbo.XXX In compt
                        Dim RSK As New dbo.YYY
                        RSK.RSK_UNITE = cpt.RES_UNITE
                        RSK.RSK_CODE = cpt.RES_CODE
                        RSK.RSK_DATE = valeurs.Item3 ' *** date
                        db.dbo.YYY.Add(RSK)
                    Next
                Try
                   Dim num As Integer = db.SaveChanges()
                Catch generatedExceptionName As OptimisticConcurrencyException
                    Dim ctxSTK = (CType(db, IObjectContextAdapter)).ObjectContext
                    ctxSTK.Refresh(RefreshMode.ClientWins, compt)
                    ctxSTK.SaveChanges()                      
                Catch monex As Exception
                    MsgBox(monex.ToString())
                End Try
```

Entity Framework 6
Windows 10
Visual Studio 2017 VB Net

Comment: Even if you could, why would the second attempt succeed? Also, an exception raised inside a catch block isn't caught.

Comment: Thks.OK, so how do you do with duplicates and Save Change () + EF 6???
I just want to avoid duplicates in the For Each loop. How?

Comment: To avoid duplicates check for existance before `Add`.

Comment: That's what I did. But this check slows down the code a lot. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

OK .... it's resolved!

```
Dim flagDuplicates = From d In db.TB_XXX Where (d.RSK_UNITE = cpt.RES_UNITE And d.RSK_CODE = cpt.RES_CODE And d.RSK_DATE = valeurs.Item3) Select d
                        If flagDuplicates.Count() = 0 Then
                            db.XXX.Add(RSK)
                        End If
```